# How to calculate values based on neighbouring rows in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I have an Xcode Swift application that is using a UITableView to display a list of results.

Each row has a value which is calculated to be the difference of a value in the next row.

When the data loads, all is good. However I noticed that, as I have now learnt with the behaviour of the TableView, is that each cell is calculated when it is about to be presented to view.

So originally I had in my code logic that said,

```
// Global variable
var previousX = 0;

// Building up cell (this happens for each cell in the table view)
----------------------------
var x = 5;
var difference = x - previousX;
previousX = x;
----------------------------
```

So this works fine when the load lists for the first time, and you scroll down.
However as soon as you scroll up, it loads the cells again. What this means is that my 'previousX' isn't neccessaily the cell above the current cell that I am building, but could be below to. So the values are sort of unpredicatble.

How can I avoid this? How can my cell ALWAYS get the 'previous/above' cell value when building the cell up? Clearly using 'previousX' being the value of the last cell that was populated is not the ideal solution.

If you need any more info from me, let me know.

thanks!

Comment: Your cells should read the data they need to display from a UITableViewDataSource. A TableViewCell only really exists to display data which is provided to it. Doing calculations in the cells themselves, especially calculations based on the position of the cell in the table, is bound to go wrong.

Comment: Thought so. So it's pretty much a rule of thumb that you should avoid attempting to do what im doing, and rather calculate these before populating the cells. The challenge is that these cells is a collection of history items. So it is pretty easy for me to calculate the difference when a new history item is created. However, the user is also able to delete a history item, which then can create incorrect difference between 2 remaining history items. Thought there was a way to better do what Im doing, but Im guessing it's not the case. :) thanks for the comment!

Comment: In the case where a user deletes a cell, you should be able to delete the data from the model, and reload the table view's data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Achive This you have to  maintain array for This:

```
// instance variable
    var previousX:[Int] = []

// Give default to array
 previousX = [Int](count: 3, repeatedValue: 0) // create array as per you need

// Building up cell (this happens for each cell in the table view)

var x = 5
var difference = x - previousX[indexPath.row - 1]
previousX[indexPath.row] = difference
```

Comment: Thanks! This pretty much helped get me to my solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use indexPath.row value as the data for each row which is unique and increase/decrease automatically depending on the cell position. It might help.